# Can I rely on HTTP referrer to estimate web page load time from my nginx server?

Tags: html, nginx, web, http-headers

I am trying to find a way to record the web page load times of my nginx server.

- Now, each page loads multiple HTTP requests and I see except for the actual HTTP Url used, the sub requests in the page have the HTTP referrer as its header and can be accessed by $http_referrer variable in Nginx.
- I can not just sum $request_times of all requests, as all requests need not be made in series. So, I want to use the timestamp of the first request i.e., the HTTP referrer request itself and the timestamp of the last request.
- I think if I use HTTP/2 protocol, I can use HTTP referrer and Connection ID together to identify a single page load and then, I can identify the last request easily. But for few reasons, I can't use HTTP/2 and I am using HTTP/1.1 with keepalive connections.  Because of this, multiple connections can be seen in a single page request and also refreshing a page can still use the old connection. So, I am unable to figure out how to use this and identify the connections from a single page request. Is there any ID that is common in all requests of a page but unique with each page load??

EDIT: I started to realize that the actual page load time can actually be still different as the size of the response can be big and it can cause more delay So, I think it is not possible this way. Any other way I can get this data? My Nginx server is a reverse proxy server and hence, I can't add any code to track and report page load times. I just need to manage at the proxy level.

I am using elasticsearch and grafana to export these stats into a graph.

Answer (score 1):

A browser side plugin like Web Developer in Firefox can give you the perfect answer. Not only the total load time, but also the time it used for DNS queries etc and the time it took to render.

I will assume you do not have access on the browser side. So you're trying to answer this question based on server side information (Nginx logs) only.

Roughly put, there are 3 phases:

1. DNS query to resolve FQDN into IP addresses. You will not be able to know the time it took to query the DNS server. That info simply not in your Nginx logs. No worries though, DNS querying is relatively fast. So not much time is spent on this step.
2. The time it takes the browser to get all files. Not just the "main" html files, but also all files it refers to. Typically css, js, images and perhaps other file types too.
3. Rendering time. Depending on how (graphically) intensive your web page is, it could take several seconds to render the page. You won't be able to measure this time either.

Let's define the "load time" as the sum of all 3 phases. You can't measure all 3, but you can get an estimate of the load time by measuring the actions in phase 2.

---

Pick a logfile in your Nginx logs. Pick a GET (or POST) request that requests a html file. This is the start time of phase 2.
Example:

```
1.2.3.4 - - [28/Mar/2021:16:21:10 +0000] "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1" 200 1316 "http://www.referrerurl.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 14_4 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.0.3 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1"
```

In the example above we have a request for /index.html from 1.2.3.4 at 16:21:10 UTC.

Now, filter the Nginx log file for this IP address and the browser identification string. You will see multiple GET (and/or POST) requests from this IP/browser

```
1.2.3.4 - - [28/Mar/2021:16:21:10 +0000] "GET /js/jquery-1.4.2.js HTTP/1.1" 200 24606 "http://www.yourwebsite.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 14_4 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.0.3 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1"
1.2.3.4 - - [28/Mar/2021:16:21:10 +0000] "GET /images/logo.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 14271 "http://www.yourwebsite.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 14_4 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.0.3 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1"
1.2.3.4 - - [28/Mar/2021:16:21:11 +0000] "GET /images/slider_button_act.png HTTP/1.1" 200 3015 "http://www.yourwebsite.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 14_4 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.0.3 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1"
```

The last HTTP request in the log before you receive another request for a html file marks the end of phase 2. In this example: 16:21:11 UTC.

The time difference between

- the first HTTP request, requesting the html file  = 16:21:10 UTC
- the last HTTP request, not reqeusting a html file = 16:21:11 UTC

is your estimate of the load time. In the example, it's 1 second.

---

For more accurate (sub second) time measurements, you may look if it's possible to log local_time to the millisecond: https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_time_local
Hint: $time_iso8601 may be easier to parse, don't know if it will display sub second resolution though.

If sub second resolution is what you're after and Nginx logs can't provide you that, you could look into other server side means such as tcpdump'ing the HTTP(S) traffic and analyze the resulting pcap dump. But then again, this is beyond making the analysis based on your Nginx log files.

P.S. I am implicitly assuming here that a html page does not include another html page. If this is the case, you'll need to have information about the structure of the website to finetune your measurements.